# Not able to add days to date

Tags: java

I am trying to add 3 days to date which is in string, am not very sure how to do this and am getting error.

```
String date = "2018-04-02 21:53:18.0";
LocalDate dateChanged = LocalDate.parse(date);

dateChanged.plusDays(3);

System.out.println(dateChanged);
```

Am getting below error

```
    Text '2018-04-02 21:53:18.0' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
```

Can someone help here please

Comment: How is this related to testing? Probably better suited for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify date format to make your parser know which of the parts represent what:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "2018-04-02 21:53:18.0";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    LocalDate dateChanged = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateChanged.plusDays(3));
}
```

Your code does not work because the default format for `parse()` method is `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` and your string does not match that format.

Where `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` is defined as:

```
    ISO_LOCAL_DATE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
            .toFormatter(ResolverStyle.STRICT, IsoChronology.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: But the print statement is just printing 2018-04-05 , instead i want it to print 2018-04-05 21:53:18.0. Can you help here.

Comment: It prints the date because you're using LocalDate. Use LocalDateTime instead.